# solve $x^2+2ix+1=0$

Tags: roots

Hey folks I'm trying to solve $x^2+2ix+1=0$.

Squaring it ($x^2+2ix=-1)^2 \implies x^4-4x=1 \implies$ ... leads nowhere

Factoring it ($x^2+2ix+1=0)^2 \implies x(x+i)+(x+1)=0 \implies$ ... leads nowhere

I know that the answer is $(-1\pm \sqrt2)i$. Any hints are appreciated.

Comment: Quadratic formula

Comment: Or complete the square

Comment: You solve it the exact same way you have presumably solved quadratic equations for years.

Comment: thank you guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Completing the square is the fastest here:
$\quad x^2+2ix+1=(x+i)^2+2 $, so
$$x^2+2ix+1=0\iff (x+i)^2=-2 \iff x+i=\pm\sqrt 2 i\iff x=(-1\pm\sqrt 2)i.$$

Answer (score -1):

**Hint**

$$x^2+2ix+(i)^2=-2 \\
(x+i)^2=-2$$

Comment: Can the downvoter explain?